# Query Optimisation left outer join 7 tables - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

Need help for faster execution and optimisation for the below.

Find the execution plan in the 2 images attached..[image] [image]
Data in all tables are as follows:

- company - 25 rows
- warranty_period - 878 rows
- company_claimtype - 216 rows
- claim_type - 25 rows
- customer - 15980 rows
- auto_handle - 25 rows
- auto_handle_condition - 31 rows
- PART_REQUIRED_RETURN - 4521 rows

The following query took almost 12 mins to execute and it contains only left outer join of all the above mentioned tables:

```
select
    company0_.ID as ID1_9_0_,
    warrantype1_.ID as ID1_36_1_,
    partsrequi2_.ID as ID1_20_2_,
    claimtype4_.ID as ID1_8_3_,
    autohandle5_.ID as ID1_4_4_,
    autohandle6_.ID as ID1_5_5_,
    customer7_.ID as ID1_14_6_,
    company0_.CREATED as CREATED2_9_0_,
    company0_.UPDATED as UPDATED3_9_0_,
    company0_.AUTO_REJECT_USER as AUTO_REJ4_9_0_,
    company0_.CLAIM_CREDIT_ORDER_HISTORY as CLAIM_CR5_9_0_,
    company0_.CLAIM_ORDER_HISTORY as CLAIM_OR6_9_0_,
    company0_.COMPANY_CODE as COMPANY_7_9_0_,
    company0_.COMPANY_NAME as COMPANY_8_9_0_,
    company0_.CONNECTED_TO_ERP as CONNECTE9_9_0_,
    company0_.DEFAULT_CUSTOMER_ID as DEFAULT16_9_0_,
    company0_.DATE_FORMAT as DATE_FO10_9_0_,
    company0_.DISPLAY_WORK_LOCATION as DISPLAY11_9_0_,
    company0_.DISTANCE_UNIT as DISTANC12_9_0_,
    company0_.ENABLE_SHIPPING_LABEL as ENABLE_13_9_0_,
    company0_.HANDLE_CREDIT_INVOICES as HANDLE_14_9_0_,
    company0_.RETURNS_PARTS_DAYS as RETURNS15_9_0_,
    warrantype1_.CREATED as CREATED2_36_1_,
    warrantype1_.UPDATED as UPDATED3_36_1_,
    warrantype1_.COMPANY_ID as COMPANY_8_36_1_,
    warrantype1_.PERIOD_CONSUMER as PERIOD_C4_36_1_,
    warrantype1_.PERIOD_PROFESSIONAL as PERIOD_P5_36_1_,
    warrantype1_.PRODUCT_GROUP as PRODUCT_6_36_1_,
    warrantype1_.PRODUCT_NO as PRODUCT_7_36_1_,
    warrantype1_.COMPANY_ID as COMPANY_8_36_0__,
    warrantype1_.ID as ID1_36_0__,
    partsrequi2_.CREATED as CREATED2_20_2_,
    partsrequi2_.UPDATED as UPDATED3_20_2_,
    partsrequi2_.COMPANY_ID as COMPANY_5_20_2_,
    partsrequi2_.PRODUCT_NO as PRODUCT_4_20_2_,
    partsrequi2_.COMPANY_ID as COMPANY_5_20_1__,
    partsrequi2_.ID as ID1_20_1__,
    claimtype4_.CREATED as CREATED2_8_3_,
    claimtype4_.UPDATED as UPDATED3_8_3_,
    claimtype4_.CATEGORY as CATEGORY4_8_3_,
    claimtype4_.CLAIM_TYPE as CLAIM_TY5_8_3_,
    claimtype4_.SORT_ORDER as SORT_ORD6_8_3_,
    claimtype4_.TEXT_KEY as TEXT_KEY7_8_3_,
    claimtypes3_.COMPANY_ID as COMPANY_2_10_2__,
    claimtypes3_.CLAIMTYPE_ID as CLAIMTYP1_10_2__,
    autohandle5_.CREATED as CREATED2_4_4_,
    autohandle5_.UPDATED as UPDATED3_4_4_,
    autohandle5_.[ACTION] as ACTION4_4_4_,
    autohandle5_.[ACTIVE] as ACTIVE5_4_4_,
    autohandle5_.[ASSIGN] as ASSIGN6_4_4_,
    autohandle5_.[COMPANY_ID] as COMPANY_8_4_4_,
    autohandle5_.[NAME] as NAME7_4_4_,
    autohandle5_.[COMPANY_ID] as COMPANY_8_4_3__,
    autohandle5_.ID as ID1_4_3__,
    autohandle6_.CREATED as CREATED2_5_5_,
    autohandle6_.UPDATED as UPDATED3_5_5_,
    autohandle6_.AUTO_HANDLE_ID as AUTO_HAN7_5_5_,
    autohandle6_.[OPERATOR] as OPERATOR4_5_5_,
    autohandle6_.[TYPE] as TYPE5_5_5_,
    autohandle6_.[VALUE] as VALUE6_5_5_,
    autohandle6_.AUTO_HANDLE_ID as AUTO_HAN7_5_4__,
    autohandle6_.ID as ID1_5_4__,
    customer7_.CREATED as CREATED2_14_6_,
    customer7_.UPDATED as UPDATED3_14_6_,
    customer7_.COMPANY_ADDRESS as COMPANY_4_14_6_,
    customer7_.STREET as STREET5_14_6_,
    customer7_.ZIPCODE as ZIPCODE6_14_6_,
    customer7_.COMPANY_ID as COMPANY_9_14_6_,
    customer7_.CUSTOMER_NO as CUSTOMER7_14_6_,
    customer7_.NAME as NAME8_14_6_ 
from
    COMPANY company0_ 
left outer join
    WARRANTY_PERIOD warrantype1_ 
        on company0_.ID=warrantype1_.COMPANY_ID 
left outer join
    PART_REQUIRED_RETURN partsrequi2_ 
        on company0_.ID=partsrequi2_.COMPANY_ID 
left outer join
    COMPANY_CLAIMTYPE claimtypes3_ 
        on company0_.ID=claimtypes3_.COMPANY_ID 
left outer join
    CLAIM_TYPE claimtype4_ 
        on claimtypes3_.CLAIMTYPE_ID=claimtype4_.ID 
left outer join
    AUTO_HANDLE autohandle5_ 
        on company0_.ID=autohandle5_.[COMPANY_ID] 
left outer join
    AUTO_HANDLE_CONDITION autohandle6_ 
        on autohandle5_.ID=autohandle6_.AUTO_HANDLE_ID 
left outer join
    CUSTOMER customer7_ 
        on company0_.DEFAULT_CUSTOMER_ID=customer7_.ID
```

Comment: There is more from the plan we need beyond the picture, but you are off to a good start. Share your execution plans using [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) here are the instructions: [How to Use Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/).

Comment: also share create table / index clauses

Comment: Please find the execution plan on the this link http://jmp.sh/v/nfHwSoOBi6mIZ6Blo9DA

Comment: Please find the create table and indexes in the file which can be downloaded from the link http://jmp.sh/v/1jleLsxw5tZvvcAEc2Ub

Answer (score 0):

What I find particularly strange is that you get about 585k records from  `PART_REQUIRED_RETURN` and then tag those along but when the server adds the `AUTO_HANDLE` data things suddenly multiply to 2.1M records. Are you sure your join takes into account the entire PK?  As your query looks right now I would assume that ID is the PK of `AUTO_HANDLE`, however the numbers seem to contradict this.  Something similar happens when adding the `AUTO_HANDLE_CONDITION` data.

In the end you are reading 3.3M rows, or about 4.5Gb of data. I don't think you can expect to bring this down to seconds.